# JavaScript modal with ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I am trying to create a modal using es6 classes.
A codePen: https://codepen.io/t411tocreate/pen/KomLzo

The idea is to get a button from the dom using `data-for-modal` attribute, get modal itself searching by `data-modal` attribute. Then `showModal` and `hideModal` methods should be bound to the element created as `Modal` class instance. Why it doesen't works ?

My JS looks like this:

```
class Modal {
  constructor(modalName) {
    this.showBtn = document.querySelector(`[data-for-modal=\'${modalName}\']`)
    this.modalWrapper = document.querySelector(`[data-modal=\'${modalName}\']`);
    this.closeBtn = document.querySelector(`[data-modal=\'${modalName}\']`).children[0].children[0].children[1];
  }

  showModal () {
    this.modalWrapper.classList.add('.ui-modal-wrappper.ui-modal-wrappper--active-modal');
  }

  hideModal () {
    this.modalWrapper.classList.remove('.ui-modal-wrappper.ui-modal-wrappper--active-modal');
  }

  this.showBtn.addEventListener('click', this.showModal);
  this.closeBtn.addEventListener('click', this.hideModal);

}

const m1 = new Modal('modal-1');
const m2 = new Modal('modal-2');
```

Comment: Because the handler is being bound by a different context `this` than the context from class Modal.

Comment: how do I make `this` refer to the constructor ?

Comment: Use `bind()`.  `this.showModal.bind(this)`

Comment: While you're making this it might be worth learning about [dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) it kinda exists, it's always best to use the platform but making your own polyfill would be cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why it doesen't works ?

Because the handler is being bound by a different context `this` than the context from class `Modal`.

**You need to bind the right context `this`:**

```
this.showBtn.addEventListener('click', this.showModal.bind(this));
this.closeBtn.addEventListener('click', this.hideModal.bind(this));
```

The function `bind` will bind that context `this` from class `Modal` and returns a new function bound to the right context.

```js
class Modal {
  constructor(modalName) {
    this.showBtn = document.querySelector(`[data-for-modal=\'${modalName}\']`)
    this.modalWrapper = document.querySelector(`[data-modal=\'${modalName}\']`);
    this.closeBtn = document.querySelector(`[data-modal=\'${modalName}\']`).children[0].children[0].children[1];
    
    this.showBtn.addEventListener('click', this.showModal.bind(this));
    this.closeBtn.addEventListener('click', this.hideModal.bind(this));
  }

  showModal() {
    console.log(this.modalWrapper);
    this.modalWrapper.classList.add('.ui-modal-wrappper.ui-modal-wrappper--active-modal');
  }

  hideModal() {
    console.log(this.modalWrapper);
    this.modalWrapper.classList.remove('.ui-modal-wrappper.ui-modal-wrappper--active-modal');
  }

  

}

const m1 = new Modal('modal-1');
const m2 = new Modal('modal-2');
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.buttons-panel {
  background: #ccc;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.ui-show-modal-btn {
  background: #3b5998;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.ui-show-modal-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .9;
}

.ui-modal-wrappper {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
}

.ui-modal-wrappper.ui-modal-wrappper--active-modal {
  display: flex;
}

.ui-modal-body {
  width: 80%;
  background: #ececec;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #333;
}

.ui-modal-body__header,
.ui-modal-body__footer {
  color: #ececec;
  background: #3b5998;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.ui-modal-body__header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.ui-modal-header__title {}

.ui-modal-header__close-btn {
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 15px;
  transition: .2s ease all;
}

.ui-modal-header__close-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .8;
}

.ui-modal-body__footer {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.ui-modal-body__content {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  color: #222;
  text-align: justify;
}

.ui-modal-body__content p {
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.ui-modal-body__content p:last-child {
  padding: 0px 0 0px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-panel">
  <button class="ui-btn ui-show-modal-btn" type="button" name="button" data-for-modal="modal-1">Show modal 1</button>

  <button class="ui-btn ui-show-modal-btn" type="button" name="button" data-for-modal="modal-2">Show modal 2</button>
</div>

<div class="ui-modal-wrappper" data-modal="modal-1">
  <div class="ui-modal-body">
    <div class="ui-modal-body__header">
      <span class="ui-modal-header__title">Modal 1 header</span>
      <span class="ui-modal-header__close-btn">x</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-modal-body__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-modal-body__footer">Modal footer</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ui-modal-wrappper" data-modal="modal-2">
  <div class="ui-modal-body">
    <div class="ui-modal-body__header">
      <span class="ui-modal-header__title">Modal 2 header</span>
      <span class="ui-modal-header__close-btn">x</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-modal-body__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-modal-body__footer">Modal footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```